# No puedo quitarme esa [imagen] de la cabeza

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Ahora mismo hay tres etiquetas genéricas que se usan para indicar que la pregunta va a tratar sobre uso de imágenes:

- [image](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image) (3 preguntas)
- [imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagen) (9 preguntas)
- [imagenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagenes) (50 preguntas)

Aunque la más utilizada es [imagenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagenes), propondría unir las tres en [imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagen), y hacer las otras dos sinónimos que apunten a esa (así nos quitaríamos el término en inglés y problemas con acentos más adelante).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hecho. Las tres etiquetas, y además la que tiene tilde, quedaron como sinónimos.

> [imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagen) (etiqueta maestra) ← [image](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image), [imagenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagenes) e [imágenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/im%c3%a1genes) (sinónimos)

Comment: Wow. Eso fue rápido.